# Component won't reload with new data when route parameters change

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've noticed when I'm on a /users/:id1 link trying to get to a new user profile page /users/:id2 it won't reload the data of the new user id I'm trying to go to but it will load fine if I come from a different page like /forums or /search

I've already tried `componentWillReceiveProps` but I'm not sure if I've implemented it right and also don't know if it's safe to use anymore b/c it might be deprecated now???

I've also tried wrapped my UserProfile with withRouter but seemed to make it worse as when I refreshed the page no data would load

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} >
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/search" component={Search}/>
            <Route exact path="/forum" component={Forum}/>
            <Route exact path="/user/:id" component={UserProfile} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

How my links look like

```
<Link className="pt-button pt-minimal" to={"/user/"+this.props.currentUserId}>My Profile</Link>
```

My attempt at componentWillReceiveProps

```
if (nextProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.setState({

        userId: nextProps.match.params.id,

    })
    this.componentWillMount();
}
```

Expected: when clicking on a link to another user profile, it redirects to new user profile with that new user profile's data

Actual: the url changes but no data reloads.

Comment: So there's a few things here. Firstly, why are you passing the current user ID as a prop into the `<Route/>`, it'll already have that available via the route props? Unless the state one you're passing from the parent is different to the route one, in which case "current" is probably not the right name. Secondly, in a similar vein, why do you store the ID in the state in the `<Route/>` component? It's already in the `props`, why duplicate it into the state?

Comment: Thirdly, you shouldn't be manually calling lifecycle methods. If there's stuff in `componentWillMount` you want to call again when you get new props, put that in a separate component method then call that in `componentWillMount` *and* when new props come in. Can you add your `<Route/>` component code, maybe in a sandbox MVE or something.

Comment: @Jayce444 ah currentUserId is the user who is currently logged in so not necessarily the user id of the profile you're trying to view. And yeah, calling the lifecycle method was weird to me too I just saw it in some StackOverflow post so I was like let's try it lol. I'll break things out into a separate method, thank you! Also what do you mean by MVE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're pretty close, but a mixture of misunderstanding lifecycle methods and when/how they are called is leading to some issues.

You probably should be using `componentDidUpdate`. I would also avoid storing the prop in state as they will then need to be kept in sync.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
    this.setState({ user: null });
    fetchUserData(this.props.match.params.id)
      .then((user) => {
        this.setState({ user: user });
      })
  }
}
```

Also, don't manually trigger the lifecycle methods (as mentioned in the comments)

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Will implement a fetchUserData kind of method.

Comment: This ended up working for me. Made a new method where I'd pass the new ID in and set the new state. :D

Comment: It should be: componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) { ...